# matching a wall texture

Tags: plaster, patching-drywall

I need to patch a few areas on a wall with the texture shown in the photos below.  Can anyone suggest what kind of product or texturing technique would match this?  It doesn't have to be a perfect match, since it's in a basement recreation room where I'm not so picky, but I'd like to at least come close.  I don't know if it matters, but I'm pretty sure this is a plaster wall rather than sheetrock.  Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: what is inside of the bumps?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a medium to heavy orange peel. Your local big-box store should sell cans of texture spray (Homax is a brand, I believe) that show what it will look like in a picture on the can.

For this type of texture , I've also seen additives you pour into your paint. It's basically some fine sand you stir into it and when you roll it on, it gives the texture. That may work for what you're looking at too. Make sure you keep stirring the paint, since the texture additive settle out over time.

I'm afraid the only real method to be sure is trial and error. This type of thing is an art, not a science. Try on some scrap cardboard or drywall pieces first.

Answer (score 1):

I thought this is called a popcorn wall. If you are based in Europe, you may find it from a brand called Marmoran (if not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like orange peel that hasn't had the peaks knocked down or smoothed. Buy a spray can of the oil based stuff from the hardware store and test it on some cardboard with the setting on a pretty heavy spray.